# Not understanding why I cant use use cx_Oracle with Django

Tags: python, django, oracle11g, cx-oracle

Question is I am trying to build a new python app, but for some strange reason I keep having an issue with cx_Oracle. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

When I do this I am able to import cx_Oracle just fine.

```
 programmer@ubuntu:~/Python_app$ python
 Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
 [GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information. 
 >>> import cx_Oracle
 >>> 

 >>> cx_Oracle 
 <module 'cx_Oracle' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cx_Oracle.so'>
```

but when I do something like this

```
 programmer@ubuntu:~/Python_app$ sudo python manage.py startapp help_desk
```

I get this error

```
Error loading cx_Oracle module: libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have checked and rechecked my paths and I can not figure out what is wrong. Here are my paths

```
programmer@ubuntu:~/Python_app$ echo $ORACLE_HOME
/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2

programmer@ubuntu:~/Python_app$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2
```

Here is the rundown of my /opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2

```
programmer@ubuntu:/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2$ tree

 ├── adrci
 ├── BASIC_README
 ├── genezi
 ├── glogin.sql
 ├── libclntsh.so -> libclntsh.so.11.1
 ├── libclntsh.so.11.1
 ├── libnnz11.so
 ├── libocci.so.11.1
 ├── libociei.so
 ├── libocijdbc11.so 
 ├── libsqlplusic.so
 ├── libsqlplus.so
 ├── ojdbc5.jar
 ├── ojdbc6.jar 
 ├── sdk
 │   ├── demo
     │   │   ├── cdemo81.c
     │   │   ├── demo.mk
     │   │   ├── occidemod.sql
     │   │   ├── occidemo.sql
     │   │   ├── occidml.cpp
     │   │   ├── occiobj.cpp
     │   │   └── occiobj.typ
 │   ├── include
     │   │   ├── ldap.h
     │   │   ├── nzerror.h
     │   │   ├── nzt.h
     │   │   ├── occiAQ.h
     │   │   ├── occiCommon.h
     │   │   ├── occiControl.h
     │   │   ├── occiData.h
     │   │   ├── occi.h
     │   │   ├── occiObjects.h
     │   │   ├── oci1.h
     │   │   ├── oci8dp.h
     │   │   ├── ociap.h
     │   │   ├── ociapr.h
     │   │   ├── ocidef.h
     │   │   ├── ocidem.h
     │   │   ├── ocidfn.h
     │   │   ├── ociextp.h
     │   │   ├── oci.h
     │   │   ├── ocikpr.h
     │   │   ├── ocixmldb.h
     │   │   ├── ocixstream.h
     │   │   ├── odci.h
     │   │   ├── oratypes.h
     │   │   ├── orid.h
     │   │   ├── ori.h
     │   │   ├── orl.h
     │   │   ├── oro.h
     │   │   ├── ort.h
     │   │   └── xa.h
     │   ├── ott
     │   ├── ottclasses.zip
     │   └── SDK_README
 ├── sqlplus
 ├── SQLPLUS_README
 ├── uidrvci
 └── xstreams.jar
```

When I try this command without sudo I get this

```
 programmer@ubuntu:~/Python_app$ python manage.py startapp help_desk
 CommandError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/programmer/Python_app/help_desk'
```

Based on a comment I'm thinking this has something to do with my permission's here is the permissions for opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2

```
  -rwxrwxr-x 1 root root     25420 Aug 24  2013 adrci
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 root root       439 Aug 24  2013 BASIC_README
  -rwxrwxr-x 1 root root     47860 Aug 24  2013 genezi
  -r-xr-xr-x 1 root root       368 Aug 24  2013 glogin.sql
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        17 May 19 14:53 libclntsh.so -> libclntsh.so.11.1
  -rwxrwxr-x 1 root root  53865194 Aug 24  2013 libclntsh.so.11.1
  -r-xr-xr-x 1 root root   7996693 Aug 24  2013 libnnz11.so
  -rwxrwxr-x 1 root root   1973074 Aug 24  2013 libocci.so.11.1
  -rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 118738042 Aug 24  2013 libociei.so
  -r-xr-xr-x 1 root root    164942 Aug 24  2013 libocijdbc11.so
  -r-xr-xr-x 1 root root   1502287 Aug 24  2013 libsqlplusic.so
  -r-xr-xr-x 1 root root   1469542 Aug 24  2013 libsqlplus.so
  -r--r--r-- 1 root root   2091135 Aug 24  2013 ojdbc5.jar
  -r--r--r-- 1 root root   2739616 Aug 24  2013 ojdbc6.jar
  drwxrwxr-x 4 root root      4096 Aug 24  2013 sdk
  -r-xr-xr-x 1 root root      9320 Aug 24  2013 sqlplus
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 root root       443 Aug 24  2013 SQLPLUS_README
  -rwxrwxr-x 1 root root    192365 Aug 24  2013 uidrvci
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 root root     66779 Aug 24  2013 xstreams.jar
```

One more thing its wierd that can import the cx_Oracle module using the python shell but, cant do it when trying to create a new app..
So im not sure whats going on.

Comment: What happens when you run it without `sudo`?

Comment: I tried it without sudo and this is what I got programmer@ubuntu:~/Python_app$ python manage.py startapp help_desk
CommandError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/programmer/Python_app/help_desk' @mmmmmpie

Comment: I think you've botched up the permissions inside of your installation. Some (if not all) of the oracle files are owned by root but your user has the proper variables and path settings.

Comment: That makes sense, what would you advise me to do to fix this? should I chown  programmer /opt/oracle/instantclient/ @mmmmmpie

Comment: You could try that. How much effort would go into reinstalling it?

Comment: No offense to Oracle but, this has been a huge pain in the neck lol, so the least amount of work would be nice. I updated my question with the perms for opt/oracle.......@mmmmmpie

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. Yes, it had something to do with my permissions. `sudo` couldn't see `ORACLE_HOME`, so all I did was add `Defaults env_keep += "ORACLE_HOME"` to `sudo visudo` and worked! Thank you for your help @mmmmmpie.

Comment: Just a note... don't run applications/databases as root.

Comment: I am a rails dev, and slowly moving to work with python so rails the gem for oracle is ruby-OCI8 which is a nightmare to get to work sometimes, I'm pretty certain thats why my db was root just for the simple fact of getting annoyed with OCI8 and I wanted to get it installed so reinstalled everything without any issue's as a user not root and It all worked fine. but any how thank you for the advice  @mmmmmpie